# In HTML it doesn't allow me to add videos from my computer(.mp4) however way I try

Tags: html, html5-video

I am adding basic video .mp4 from my Windows 10 laptop in HTML but it doesn't pick up the video at all. I tried to open in any browser it doesn't open.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide a relevant code sample so we can try to help you? Also, what is it exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Did you try to use the `<video>` element to show video in HTML?

Comment: @LaurentC I am trying to just add a vedio to my html

Comment: @didv097 i did use with <vedio>... </vedio>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Homepage</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <h1>Homepage</h1>
  <p>Welcome to the homepage. Learn more about my <a href="favorite-colors.html">favorite colors</a>.</p>
  <h2>Video</h2>
  <p>I have included an example video file on the page.</p>
  <video controls>
            <source src="video/example.mp4">
            <source src="video/example.ogv">
            <source src="video/example.webm">
 
            
  </video>        
 </body>
 
</html> @LaurentC

Comment: @sg thank you for sharing the code, although you would normally update the question itself, not post it in the comments like that. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am reproducing the relevant parts of your code here for explanation purposes.

This is the correct HTML markup to include videos:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="/video/example.mp4" type="video/mp4"> // on your server, is your file 'example.mp4' located at /video/example.mp4 ?
  <source src="/video/example.webm" type="video/webm"> // on your server, is your file 'example.webm' located at /video/example.webm?
</video>
```

I suspect that you are possibly not using the correct filepath for your video files.

As a test, try replacing the content in the `src` attribute with a video from an online source.

So your code will look like this now

```
<video controls>
  <source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The example video should be displayed on your page now.

So double check the path to the video files and make sure it is correct, because other than that the code is OK. (added / to the beginning of the filepath to refer to your root directory.) If your video files are located in the root directory, then use `src="example.mp4`

You can find more info on the video tag here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video